# reusing a controller method from another controller method (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a fairly complex method in my controller that basically outputs data to be used in a view to create a donut graph.

```
def courses_allocated
  course_id = params[:course_id];
  client_id = params[:client_id];

  override_client_id = get_client_id_for_current_user

  unless override_client_id.nil?
    client_id = override_client_id
  end

  category_course_enrollments = CourseEnrollment.select("course_categories.title, COUNT(*) as count").
    joins("INNER JOIN courses ON course_enrollments.course_id = courses.id").
    joins("INNER JOIN course_categories ON courses.course_category_id = course_categories.id").
    group("course_categories.id").
    order("course_categories.title")

  course_enrollments = CourseEnrollment.select("COUNT(*) as count, course_enrollments.course_id, courses.title").
    joins("INNER JOIN courses ON course_enrollments.course_id = courses.id").
    joins("INNER JOIN course_categories ON courses.course_category_id = course_categories.id").
    group("course_enrollments.course_id").
    order("course_categories.title")                

  unless course_id.blank? 
    category_course_enrollments = category_course_enrollments.where("course_enrollments.course_id = ?" , course_id.to_i)
    course_enrollments = course_enrollments.where("course_enrollments.course_id = ?" , course_id.to_i)
  end

  unless client_id.blank?
    category_course_enrollments = category_course_enrollments.where("courses.client_id = ?", client_id)
    course_enrollments = course_enrollments.where("courses.client_id = ?", client_id)
  end

  @category_data = []
  @course_assigned_data = []
  @course_assigned_detail_data = []

  category_course_enrollments.each do |category_course_enrollment|
    @category_data.push([category_course_enrollment.title, category_course_enrollment.count]);
  end

  course_enrollments.each do |course_enrollment|
    not_started = CourseEnrollment.select("COUNT(patient_id) AS total_not_started").
      where('started IS NULL').
      where('course_id = ?', course_enrollment.course_id).first.total_not_started

    in_progress = CourseEnrollment.select("COUNT(patient_id) AS total_in_progress").
      where('started IS NOT NULL').
      where('completed IS NULL').
      where('course_id = ?', course_enrollment.course_id).first.total_in_progress

    completed = CourseEnrollment.select("COUNT(patient_id) AS total_completed").
      where('completed IS NOT NULL').
      where('course_id = ?', course_enrollment.course_id).first.total_completed

    @course_assigned_data.push([course_enrollment.title, course_enrollment.count]);
    @course_assigned_detail_data.push({'name'=>course_enrollment.title + " Not Started", 'y'=> not_started, 'color'=>'#ff8800'});
    @course_assigned_detail_data.push({'name'=>course_enrollment.title + " In Progress", 'y'=> in_progress, 'color'=>'#0088ff'});
    @course_assigned_detail_data.push({'name'=>course_enrollment.title + " Completed", 'y'=> completed ,'color'=>'#44cc44'});
  end
end
```

The View for the donut graph (besides the input for a form is:)

```
<div id="reportcoursesallocatedgraph">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
new IS.ReportCoursesAllocated('Course Allocated', <%= raw(ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(@category_data)); %>,  <%= raw(ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(@course_assigned_data)); %>,  <%= raw(ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(@course_assigned_detail_data)); %>, 'reportcoursesallocatedgraph');
</script>
```

I want to reuse the logic from courses_allocated from a method in the same class; def dashboard. (The dashboard method basically creates a bunch of different graphs)

Should I make a private method that they can both share?

Comment: Constructive, not critical: take some time to make that controller method far, far more terse. There's way too much logic in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the logic is identical, then you can just alias dashboard to courses_allocated. To do that, you can put this right below the courses_allocated action method.

```
alias dashboard courses_allocated
```

Comment: The logic in dashboard contains courses_allocated + some other code. The private method seems to work. (which can be called from both methods, but it just doesn't seem like the best approach, but it works)

Comment: I would also move those queries into the CourseEnrollment model to get them out of the controller. In general, a controller action shouldn't be more than 5 lines or so at a maximum. If you have more than that, it is a sign that you need to do some refactoring.  You should also check out decent_exposure, as it lets you expose things to controllers and views similarly to how "let" works in rspec. Putting some of that code into expose blocks might eliminate the need for the private method.